# Would S3 Select speed up Spark analyses on Parquet files?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

You can use [S3 Select with Spark on Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3select.html) and [with Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3-select.html), but only for CSV and JSON files.  I am guessing that S3 Select isn't offered for columnar file formats because it wouldn't help that much.

Let's say we have a data lake of people with `first_name`, `last_name` and `country` columns.

If the data is stored as CSV files and you run a query like `peopleDF.select("first_name").distinct().count()`, then S3 will transfer all the data for all the columns to the ec2 cluster to run the computation.  This is really inefficient because we don't need all the `last_name` and `country` data to run this query.

If the data is stored as CSV files and you run the query with S3 select, then S3 will only transfer the data in the `first_name` column to run the query.

```
spark
  .read
  .format("s3select")
  .schema(...)
  .options(...)
  .load("s3://bucket/filename")
  .select("first_name")
  .distinct()
  .count()
```

If the data is stored in a Parquet data lake and `peopleDF.select("first_name").distinct().count()` is run, then S3 will only transfer the data in the `first_name` column to the ec2 cluster.  Parquet is a columnar file format and this is one of the main advantages.

So based on my understanding, S3 Select wouldn't help speed up an analysis on a Parquet data lake because columnar file formats offer the S3 Select optimization out of the box.

I am not sure because a coworker is certain I am wrong and because [S3 Select supports the Parquet file format](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-s3-announces-new-features-for-s3-select/).  Can you please confirm that columnar file formats provide the main optimization offered by S3 Select?

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question. I don't have any real numbers, though I have done the S3 select binding code in the hadoop-aws module. Amazon EMR have some values, as do databricks.

For CSV IO Yes, S3 Select will speedup given aggressive filtering of source data, e.g many GB of data but not much back. Why? although the read is slower, you save on the limited bandwidth to your VM.

For Parquet though, the workers split up a large file into parts and schedule the work across them (Assuming a splittable compression format like snappy is used), so > 1 worker can work on the same file. And they only read a fraction of the data (==bandwidth benefits less), But they do seek around in that file (==need to optimise seek policy else cost of aborting and reopening HTTP connections)

I'm not convinced that Parquet reads in the S3 cluster can beat a spark cluster if there's enough capacity in the cluster and you've tuned your s3 client settings (for s3a this means: seek policy, thread pool size, http pool size) for performance too.

Like I said though: I'm not sure. Numbers are welcome.

Comment: When you run `peopleDF.select("first_name").distinct().count()` on a Parquet data lake, does all the data in the `first_name`, `last_name` and `country` columns get transferred to the ec2 cluster or is only the data in the `first_name` column transferred?  I'll run some benchmarking and report back.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The S3 Select APIs only support filtering and selecting on rows. Things like count are done in the cluster. Oh, one other detail about S3 Select and parquet: the output of the select comes back as JSON or CSV, so the normal parquet engine (with its predicate push down, etc), doesn't get involved here. So I don't know how it's been wired up in EMR or Databricks. Ask them....

Comment: All quite vague is my take

Comment: sorry you feel that way. Please take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15229 "Add FileSystem builder-based openFile() API to match createFile(); S3A to implement S3 Select through this API" if you want the detail; or look at the code in https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/select and tests at https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/select

Answer (score 1):

Came across this spark package for s3 select on parquet [1]

[1] https://github.com/minio/spark-select